# How to deal with too many wires when replacing fan receiver?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I bought a new universal remote and receiver for my ceiling fan, and opening up the canopy there are more wires than expected (but perhaps I should have).

I've got wires coming from the fan labeled Uplight, Downlight, Motor L, and Motor N but the receiver only has Light and Fan.

Am I correct to assume I could wire Motor N (Neutral, I'm guessing) to the white wire coming into the receiver from the box and just wire the Motor L (Line, right?) to the receiver's fan wire?

Also, can I just wire BOTH the up and downlight wires to the receiver's light wire?

Comment: Does your fan have 2 separate groups of Lights which would be beneficial to control separately?

Comment: It does - there are uplights and downlights, but I don't particularly care if they come on together or not. At the moment I don't even have the uplights in.

Comment: If you don't care to separately control the lights, then you can connect them both to the receivers `Light` wire.